# OBIEE12c configuration assistant failed with Cannot find identity keystore file

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, obiee

I am getting the following error while run the obiee12c configuration assistant.

> weblogic.nodemanager.common.ConfigException: Identity key store file not found DemoIdentity.jks

The following is the error log:

> <Feb 6, 2021 10:16:38,503 PM JST>    <Cannot find identity keystore file <DOMAIN_HOME>/security/DemoIdentity.jks on server AdminServer>
> <Feb 6, 2021 10:16:38,504 PM JST>    <Inconsistent security configuration, weblogic.management.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot find identity keystore file <DOMAIN_HOME>/security/DemoIdentity.jks on server AdminServer>
> <Feb 6, 2021 10:16:38,504 PM JST>    <Not listening for SSL, weblogic.management.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot find identity keystore file <DOMAIN_HOME>/security/DemoIdentity.jks on server AdminServer.>
> <Feb 6, 2021 10:16:38,505 PM JST>    <The server is unable to create a server socket for listening on channel "DefaultSecure[iiops][5]". The address 127.0.0.1 might be incorrect or another process is using port 7002: java.io.IOException: Cannot find identity keystore file <DOMAIN_HOME>/security/DemoIdentity.jks on server AdminServer>

Comment: Needs more details. What exact version? What host OS? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the workaround to resolve the issue.

Step 1: Browse to the location '<DOMAIN_HOME>\security'

Step 2: Copy the file "DemoIdentity.jks" from '<DOMAIN_HOME>\security' location and paste to '<NODEMANAGER_HOME>\security' location

Step 3: Re-run the obiee12c configuration assistant.